# Sending requests from spa to .netcore web api using adaljs always returns 401

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, adal.js

I have a spa that is sending a get request to a web api.

When I dont have the authorize attribute, I am able to get the values (of course!). Adding the authorize attribute always returns a 401 response.

After scratching my head on this for 2 weeks straight, I feel like only SO gods can help.

I have the following questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. How can I log the incoming token on the server side?
   (Just so I can validate it at jwt.io)

Assuming my keys, tenant, client(id) etc are properly set up,

My code on spa is like this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('todoApp')
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'adalAuthenticationService', '$location', function ($scope, $http, adalService, $location) {
        $scope.apiData = [];
        $scope.login = function () {
            adalService.login().then(function () {
                console.log('yay');
            });
        };
        $scope.logout = function () {
            adalService.logOut();
        };
        $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
            return viewLocation === $location.path();
        };

        $scope.getData = function () {
            // #1: Set up ADAL
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
                clientId: 'myclientid',
                postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location
            });

            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
                console.log('Signed in as: ' + user.userName);
            } else {
                console.log('Not signed in');
            }

            var tokenStored;
            authContext.acquireToken(
                'https://graph.windows.net',
                function (error, token) {

                    // TODO: Handle error obtaining access token
                    if (error || !token) {
                        console.log('Error no token');
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("token is:" + token);
                    tokenStored = token;

                    $http.get('https://localhost:44301/api/values', {
                        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenStored, }
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.apiData = response.data;
                        console.log(response);
                        alert('Data recieved');
                    });
                });

        };
    }]);
```

My Api Startup.cs looks like this:

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            //ToDo: Implement Logger Factory
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();



            // Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
            // global policy - assign here or on each controller
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");



            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
            //    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });

            app.UseMvc();

        }
```

My controller method looks like this

```
[Route("api/values")]
    [Authorize]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
 // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var results = _interconnectCodesRepository.GetCodes();
                return Ok(results);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
}
}
```

Any suggestions or hints will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the token from .net core web API project, we can add `AuthenticationFailed` event like below:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"]),
    Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed= AuthenticationFailed
    }
});

private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext authenticationFailedContext)
{         
    Debug.WriteLine(authenticationFailedContext.Request.Headers["authorization"]);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

The token you were acquiring using the resrouce `https://graph.windows.net`  in the code is for the **Azure Graph REST** instead of your API. There is no need to acquire the token manually in the client for the SPA application. The ADAL library will acquire and append the token based on the resource automatically. We just only need to init which endpoints we want to request. Here is the js code for your reference:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['AdalAngular']).config(['$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function ($httpProvider, adalProvider) {

    //{Array} endpoints - Collection of {Endpoint-ResourceId} used for automatically attaching tokens in webApi calls.
    var endpoints = {
        "https://localhost:44327/": "https://adfei.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI",
    };

    adalProvider.init(
    {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: 'adfei.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: 'e2354bba-e915-4cb8-a48d-bcda101b8603',
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        endpoints: endpoints,
    },
    $httpProvider
    );
}])

myApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'adalAuthenticationService', '$location', 'toGoListSvc', function ($scope, $http, adalService, $location, toGoListSvc) {
    $scope.double = function (value) { return value * 2; };

    $scope.login = function () {
        adalService.login();
    };
    $scope.logout = function () {
        adalService.logOut();
    };

    $scope.getData = function () {
        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $http.get('https://localhost:44327/api/ToGoList').success(function (results) {
            console.log(results)
            $scope.toGoList = results;
        });
    }
}]);
```

For the web API side, we need to specify the the `Authority` and `Audience` or other parameters as you wanted( refer the first piece of code).

On the Azure side, we need to register two web applications. One presents the client and the other presents the resource protected by Azure AD. For example, in my test scenario, I registered ToDoSPA and ToGoAPI and grant the permission as figure below:
[image]

And to make the ToDoSPA application integrate with Azure AD with implicit flow for the SPA app, we also need to modify its manifest to set the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true`.

In addition, here are some helpful links about protecting the web API with Azure AD:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

### Update( custom AudienceValidator)

```
// Configure the app to use Jwt Bearer Authentication
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters=new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        AudienceValidator =  (audiences, securityToken, validationParameters) =>
        {
            string[] allowedAudiences = { "https://adfei.onmicrosoft.com/TodoListService", "https://graph.windows.net" };
            return allowedAudiences.Contains<string>(audiences.First<string>());
        },
    },
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"]),
    //Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],              
});
```

Comment: Thank you for such a clear and concise answer. After making the suggested changes. I am not seeing any errors on the debug console, (I was previously).
However on my SPA, I am getting this error on the console
err :AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'a77c3345-3962-40cf-8518-81baac0ace43'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
Trace ID: 94c920d0-68e3-49aa-9a17-4d9d84314631
Correlation ID: e6b165f4-b069-4815-905b-47a3ad9f8960
Timestamp: 2016-12-29 16:04:23Z

Comment: If you were developing an single-tenant app and register the app through the Azure portal, we are not require to give the consent to the app since the consent already given when we register them. In the other scenario, we need to grant the permission to the app first.

Comment: And we can grant the permission for the organization with admin consent. To initiate the admin consent grant request, we can construct the URL like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&prompt=admin_consent` and login in using the admin account of that tenant.( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code))

Comment: Getting an interesting response when I try your solution. When I sign in using the url I constructed with the above mentioned parameters, it sends me to this url

localhost:44326/?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=AADSTS70005%3a+The+WS-Federation+sign-in+response+message+contains+an+unsupported+OAuth+parameter+value+in+the+encoded+wctx%3a+%27response_type%27%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+5254259f-f541-4a66-9f56-81f3e4390f54%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+28bea07f-c341-4cc8-8e44-04125250bdc2%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2016-12-30+05%3a37%3a38Z#/Home

And no admin consent prompt pops up

Comment: Heres my url as suggested

login.microsoftonline.com/822b40bf-29d6-4738-a105-56031e970a12/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code‌​&client_id=27ae47d0-28dd-4b0c-9c19-a0b31d48f767&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44326/#/Home&prompt=admin_consent

Comment: @w2olves When I tried the URL abolve, I got the error that `Tenant name '822b40bf-29d6-4738-a105-56031e970a‌​12' specified is not a valid DNS name`, please ensure the tenant is correct, you can check the tenant through the [old Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/)->local your tenant-Applicaitons->View endpoints, you can find the correct authorization endpoint with the tenant. By the way, how did you register the app?

Comment: I replaced the tenantid with tenant name and it seems to be a valid url

login.microsoftonline.com/defenderdirect1.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=27ae47d0-28dd-4b0c-9c19-a0b31d48f767&response_type=code&redirect_uri=localhost:44326/#/H%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bome&prompt=admin_con%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsent

(add https:// before localhost for full url)

Still no admin consent.

On the Api Side I am getting this error

System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Comment: To grant the consent, please ensure the `prompt=admin_consent`. And for the exception of web API, it seems you were set the incorrect `Authority`. The `Authority` should be like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`

Comment: Thanks I believe this is finally working. Is there a way I can declare multiple audiences for my web api ?

Comment: Yes, to valid the multiple audiences we can provide the custom audience validator. Please see the updated code in the orignal post.